# dbus activiation with arguments

Tags: dbus

I like to control a third-party application from my application via dbus.

However, the third-party application has some parameters that cannot be controlled by it's dbus interfaces but must be set by command line at service activation.

How can I pass those arguments to the service by time of the activation?

Answer (score 0):

If they are static, put them in the `Exec=` line of the D-Bus `.service` file for that service.

If they need to be dynamic, it is not possible. If so, I suggest you file a bug against the service you are trying to start, requesting that they expose those options over D-Bus.

Comment: Ok.  I need to pass them by dbus, and the service won't support that. I guess I have to implement a stub activation service by myself that receives the arguments by dbus and in turn launches the real service passing them by command line.